# How fire EXCEL event BeforeDoubleClick BEFORE SelectionChange?

Tags: excel, events, vba

I want to **fire** the *BeforeDoubleClick*-event **BEFORE** the *SelectionChange*-event for an EXCEL work-sheet.

The *order* is normally the other way round: **SelectionChange-event** first, and later **BeforeDoubleClick-event**.

My goal is to **either** run MyDoubleClickCode, if there a *double-click*, **or** if NOT, run *MyChangeSelectionCode*.

The problem relies in the order of event-triggering!

My **best** solution comes here:

```
    ' This Event is **MAYBE** fired secondly and runs the MyDoubleClickCode
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
        dblFlag = true
        ...
        MyDoubleClickCode
        ...
    End Sub

    ' This event is always fired AND runs first
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        dblFlag = false
        alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        Application.OnTime alertTime, "MyChangeSelectionSub"
    End Sub

    ' Userdefined subroutine which will run one second after an event ( doubleclick or not).
    public sub MyChangeSelectionSub() 
        If NOT dblFlag then
            ...
            MyChangeSelectionCode
            ...
        End if
    End Sub
```

I use **OnTime** in my SelectionChange-event to call the MyChangeSelectionSub  one second after a selection-change is triggered. This gives times to handle an  BeforeDoubleClick-event and do the MyDoubleClickCode - if the cell was also double-clicked. My wanted logic is reached , BUT...

... it is of course very clumpsy and not satisfying: I have to wait **one second** before the MyChangeSelectionSub starts, instead of **just after** the BeforeDoubleClick-event has been dealed with.

Maybee there is a kind of **logic** to make this happend? Any idea?

**EDIT**: I've edited the code-exampel to be more clear about my problem! And I know now that I can't change the order of events, but how to not use the onTime solution??

Comment: You can't change the order of the events. Your code seems to be a bit confusing though. I'd probably do something like set a flag in one event so you know you need to do something extra in the second event.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. The  'code' is just an 'too basic' exampel, and I use of course flags. But it doesn't resolve my problem: I need the ChangeSelection-logic to happend whether the BeforeDoubleClick is fired or not!

Comment: Like @DavidG says that order is determined by VBA.  You shouldn't have to wait, if you have a variable which tells you which state you're in, it would know not to process anything in SelectionChange and simply wait until BeforeDoubleClick fires to enter a new mode of operation.  Without additional code or letting us know what you want to achieve, it's hard to comment beyond this.

Comment: @DavidG. I've edited the code, so it hopefully is  more clear about my problem. The main-problem is that I have to wait to execute the ChangeSelectionCode, till after an eventual BeforeDoubleClick-event, which itself  fires after the ChangeSelection-event. And the BeforeDoubleClick-event will maybe not be fired ...

Answer (score 0):

This "works" for me, but it doesn't seem stable.  Probably the timing of the OnTime method causes an "uncomfortable pause" in execution that we might need to accept.  (or improve upon.)

```
'worksheet (Name) is "Sheet17" in the VBA Properties window
'worksheet Name is "Sheet1" as shown in the worksheet tab in the application Excel

Private double_click_detected As Boolean
Private SelectionChange_target As Range

' This Event is **MAYBE** fired secondly and runs the MyDoubleClickCode
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  double_click_detected = True
  '...
  MsgBox "MyDoubleClickCode"
  '...
End Sub

' This event is always fired AND runs first
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set SelectionChange_target = Target
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Sheet17.MyChangeSelectionSub"
End Sub

' Userdefined subroutine which will run one second after an event ( doubleclick or not).
Public Sub MyChangeSelectionSub()
  If Not double_click_detected Then
    '...
    MsgBox "MyChangeSelectionCode"
    '...
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry to say: it is exactly he same mecanism as I use in my question. It does not add to any solving out

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for a similar issue, to avoid Worksheet_SelectionChange before the event Worksheet_BeforeRightClick on https://www.herber.de/forum/archiv/1548to1552/1550413_Worksheet_BeforeRightClick.html (in german) and used it for my test sub.
The whole list of virtual key codes you find on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)'just for sleep
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
Const VK_LBUTTON = &H1 'Left mouse button
Const VK_RBUTTON = &H2 'Right mouse button
Const VK_SHIFT = &H10'Shiftkey just for fun to exit the sub


  Sub TestGetAsyncKeyState()
  
     Dim RMouseClick As Long, LMouseClick As Long
     Dim RMouseClickpr As Long, LMouseClickpr As Long
     Dim lShift As Long, iC As Integer
     
     iC = 0
     Do
        DoEvents
        lShift = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)
        
        RMouseClickpr = RMouseClick
        LMouseClickpr = LMouseClick
  
        RMouseClick = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)
        LMouseClick = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)
        
        If RMouseClick <> RMouseClickpr Or LMouseClick <> LMouseClickpr Then Debug.Print vbLf; CStr(iC); ":"
        If RMouseClick <> RMouseClickpr Then Debug.Print "Right: "; RMouseClick; "Previous: "; RMouseClickpr
        If LMouseClick <> LMouseClickpr Then Debug.Print "Left : "; LMouseClick; "Previous: "; LMouseClickpr
  '      If RMouseClick <> RMouseClickpr Or LMouseClick <> LMouseClickpr Then Stop
        
        Sleep (1000)
        
        iC = iC + 1
        If iC > 120 Then Stop '2
        
     Loop While GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) = 0 'End Loop by pressing any of the Shift-Keys
  
  End Sub
```

It works for mouseclick (1), shortly held mousebutton (-32767) and longer held mousebutton (-32768). Unfortunately not for doubleclick.

Attention: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate says that it detects the physical mousebuttons. If someone changed the setting it will not detect the correct button. MS says you can correct that with GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON).

Hope it  helps.